# How can I modify a widget's attributes in a ModelForm's __init__() method?

Tags: django, widget, django-forms

I want to programatically modify the widget attributes of a field in a Django ModelForm's **init**() method.  Thus far, I've tried the following

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_checkbox'].widget_attrs(forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'onclick':'return false;'}))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_checkbox'].widget.attrs['onclick'] = 'return false;'
```

Comment: or, better, `attrs['onclick'] = 'return false'`

Comment: Thanks -- that worked. Any idea what "widget_attrs" is meant to do?

Comment: @Daneil, can you expound on that?

Comment: `widget_attrs` is a method on the field class which is used to return attributes that should be added to the widget, based on the current field class, eg. `max_length` for `CharFields`. You shouldn't overwrite it the way you tried to, because it is necessary to have the field working correctly...

Answer (score 4):

Bernhard's answer used to work on 1.7 and prior, but I couldn't get it to work on 1.8.

However this works:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_checkbox'].widget = forms.widgets.Checkbox(attrs={'onclick': 'return false;'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem as James Lin on Django 1.10, but got around it by updating the `attrs` dictionary rather than assigning a new widget instance. In my case, I couldn't guarantee the attribute key existed in the dictionary.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_checkbox'].widget.attrs.update({'onclick': 'return false;'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing, but not necessarily on initialisation. In my case I had to set-up a specific id to work with my AJAX function. The answer was similar to kmctown above, but I didn't use the **init**, just created a normal function within the form class as per below:

```
def type_attr(self, id_val):
    self.fields['type'].widget.attrs.update({'id':id_val})
```

Then, in views:

```
form=YourForm(request.POST or None)
form.type_attr(id_val)
```

This worked in my case.