# Customize username and password field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

First, How can I set `min_length` for `username`?
`ChachaUser._meta.get_field('username').min_length = 2` doesn't work.

Second, How can I place `placeholder` for `password1` and `password2`?
`forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder' : "6자리 이상"}),` doesn't work.

This is my customized `User` model and `UserCreationForm`.

`models.py`

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)

phone_regex = RegexValidator(
    regex=r'^\d{11}$',
    message=" '-' 없이 입력해주세요",
)

username_regex = RegexValidator(
    regex=r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$',
    message='아이디는 영어와 숫자로만 구성되어야 합니다.'
)



class ChachaUser(AbstractUser):

    birth = models.DateField("생년월일")
    name = models.CharField(
        "이 름",
        max_length=4
    )
    gender = models.CharField(
        "성 별",
        max_length=1,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        default='M'
    )

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        "핸드폰",
        validators=[phone_regex],
        max_length=11
    )

    job = models.CharField(
        "직 업",
        max_length=20,
    )

    # python manage.py createsuperuser 할 때 나오는 항목
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'birth',
        'name',
        'gender',
        'phone_number',
        'job',
        'email'
    ]

ChachaUser._meta.get_field('username').verbose_name = '아이디'
ChachaUser._meta.get_field('username').validators = [username_regex]
ChachaUser._meta.get_field('username').max_length = 20
ChachaUser._meta.get_field('username').min_length = 2
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    birth = forms.DateField(
        label="생년월일",
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
            years=range(1970, 2015)
        ),
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + (
            'name',
            'gender',
            'birth',
            'phone_number',
            'job',
        )
        exclude = ('email', )
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': '알파벳, 숫자만 가능(20자 이내)'}
            ),
            'phone_number' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder' : "ex) 01012341234"}
            ),
            'job' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder' : "ex) 한국대 철학과, 선생님 등(20자 이내)"}
            ),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder' : "6자리 이상"}
            ),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder' : "6자리 이상"}
            ),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first question:

```
from django.core import validators    
class ChachaUser(AbstractUser):
    ..................
    AbstractUser._meta.get_field('username').validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(2)]
```

For second question your couldn't change `password1` in `Meta.widgets` because it is not a model field. You can override widget in `__init__` method instead.

Comment: Question. 1. Is it `AbstractUser`, not `ChachaUser`?    2. It occurs error: `module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'validators'`

Comment: @user3595632 I have fixed `validators` import. About `AbstractUser` or `ChachaUser` it seems that it doesn't matter what uses but I prefer and usually change user model fields inside user model.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone looking for how to "override widget in `__init__` method instead." as mentioned by Anna Vracheva's answer to OP's second question. Here's a little code snippet to help:

```
from django.forms import PasswordInput

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

For more info check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961946/how-can-i-modify-a-widgets-attributes-in-a-modelforms-init-method).